# Compiler cannot find an enum type. (Battleship game)

Tags: java, oop

I'm trying to write a Battleship game.
First i made a class called `Tile` to represent one block of a 2D array that will become the battleground board:

```
public class Tile {
    public enum type{SEA, SHIP, HIT, MISS};
    int x,y;
    public type tile_type;
    public Tile(int x,int y, type type){
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.tile_type = type;
     }
}
```

Next i created a class called `Board` and in the constructor I want to make every tile to have the tile type `SEA`:

```
public class Board{
    static int Dimension = 7;
    Tile[][] Matrix = null;
    public Board(Tile[][] Matrix){
        Matrix = new Tile[Dimension][Dimension];
        for(int i=0; i<=Dimension;i++){
            for(int u=0;u<=Dimension;u++){
                Matrix[i][u].tile_type = type.SEA;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is where the Java compiler says that it cannot find the variable type in **type.SEA**.

I don't understand where the problem is.

Comment: You need to replace `type.SEA` with `Tile.type.SEA` because `tile` is an inner enum in class `Tile`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you did not import `type` in `Board`, you can add the outer class explictly:

```
Matrix[i][u].tile_type = Tile.type.SEA;
```